# What are these errors for in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an online C# and Unity3D course and I've got a problem. I can't seem to find out why I am getting all of these errors.

Here is a like to the errors that I am getting:
http://i.imgur.com/rsRjDh1.png

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 100.0f;
    public bool canMoveSideways = false;

    void Update ()
    {
        Movement ();
    }

    void Movement ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
        {
                Debug.Log ("Key UpArrow Pressed.");

                this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime));
        } 
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
        {
                Debug.Log ("Key DownArrow Pressed.");

                this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0, 0, -speed * Time.deltaTime));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
        {
            if (canMoveSideways) 
            {
                Debug.Log ("Key LeftArrow Pressed.");

                this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
            } 
            else
            {
                Debug.Log ("Key LeftArrow Pressed Rotate");

                this.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
            }
        } 
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
        {
            if (canMoveSideways) 
            {
                Debug.Log ("Key RightArrow Pressed Rotate");

                this.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
            }
            else(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                Debug.Log ("Key RightArrow Pressed.");

                this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Key W Pressed.");

            this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Key S Pressed.");

            this.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the first relevant error message in the question itself. A screenshot of the error is not sufficient. Including it in the question makes it easier to answer and easier for others with similar issues to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in line 53. I guess you forgot to remove the if clause complete (test is still there)